# Does Firefox support any truly cursive fonts?

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I'm trying to build a web page and need some kind of fairly distinct cursive font (not too crazy, but still distinguishable from standard print).  However, when I look at this page in Firefox:  https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html

My browser renders all of them in an approximately standard font--none of them look nearly cursive enough.  Since this is just an out-of-the-box installation of Firefox, I imagine this is how it will render on most users' screen if they're using the same.

Is there any way to force render a more cursive font for someone using standard Firefox?

Comment: Browsers generally don't come with any fonts, they use the ones installed on the system. If you want all your user to have a same font, then use a web font.

Comment: Will you be using font-style: italic on a standard font? Why not choose a truly italic font from Google or Typekit that will instead of skewing the regular font load the italic font version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned earlier, the font in that example varies depending on device, not browser.
When you set a non-specific font-family in your stylesheets, e.g. `font-family:sans-serif;` or `font-family:cursive;` what font that actually gets used will depend entirely on that visitors operating system and what fonts are installed there.

In that link it shows you various system fonts that may or may not be installed, with system defaults as a fallback, with a picture next to each showing what it should look like if your system has that font. This will differ from person to person. It gets quite complicated when you consider that sometimes the fallback fonts can even vary between OS versions.

So for more complete control, many developers turn to webfonts. I use a lot of Google fonts for my websites; https://fonts.google.com/

There are different ways of using a webfont, but I find this way simplest;

```css
/*put imports at the top of your stylesheet*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap');

h2 {font-family:"Lobster", cursive;}
```

```html
<h2>I'm A Webfont</h2>
```